# NFC readers and Match on Card (MOC) compatibility

Tags: nfc, smartcard-reader, contactless-smartcard

this question is not related to programming but instead is a theoretical question about the possible compatibily of a generic NFC reader and the Match on Card (MOC) technology.

The Match on Card technology that allows the validation of the biometric data of the user/owner against the biometric data stored on a smartcard without having to extract the data from the card, because the comparison is done directly on the card by the card (the smartcard includes a microprocessor).

Here is more info
http://www.e-xpertsolutions.com/images/pdf/moc/3_BiometricMOC.pdf

I'm having trouble finding a NFC reader that explicitly states the MOC compatibility, so my question is this: **Will every NFC reader be able to work with the MOC technology?**

I tend to believe that if a NFC reader/writer can transmit data to the card, then it should *physically* be able to do the MOC thing but I'm not sure and I don't want to buy a device that will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume that you refer to a contactless smartcard reader (or, if you want to call it that way, an "NFC reader") that is connected to a processing system (e.g. a PC, a smartphone, etc. that is capable of collecting biometric/sensor data, of controlling the contactless reader, and of pre-processing and sending the biometric data through the reader).*

Yes, every contactless reader that is capable of talking to your card will be suitable for a Match-on-Card system. The reader is a simple interface device that connects your card to your processing system. Consequently, the reader will not be the critical component that defines MOC capabilities. It's rather the processing system that's connected to that reader (*and as SO is an exchange for programmers and programming-related questions, I assume that **you** will design the software that runs on that processing system* ;-) ) that determines if the system does template-on-card, match-on-card or system-on-card.